# PHP -> mysqli sometimes lagging to a halt. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm the only user on a protected development site. I have a card table that is refreshed every 2 seconds with PHP -> MySQL queries. I've run these queries individually with timers and they all occur in under 0.01s. I can activate functions such as the one below fine, and the result is quick. However, if I spam the function 10 times (from clicking on a button that activates it quickly) then something strange will happen. mysqli will SELECT perfectly fine, and even run UPDATE queries but the UPDATE queries will effect 0 rows instead of the usual 1. No errors show up anywhere. After about 2 minutes, functionality will return to normal whereby UPDATE will now effect 1 row as expected, and I only see "2" on the screen (for the echo debugging test).

The following code will run fine everywhere during the problem, without error. I will simply see "234" on the screen showing that the SQL database is being successfully communicated with for the SELECT statements. The UPDATE statements also seem to go through, but as I say they effect only 0 rows instead of the usual 1. After waiting 2 minutes or so after I stop spamming the function, the UPDATE statements will effect the rows normally.

```
function sitDown($seat,$playername,$pass) {
    global $conn;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    #where $seat is INT of seat number (1-9)
    $seatcheck="seat" . $seat . "_player";
    $chipscheck="seat" . $seat . "_chips";
    mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE);
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT $seatcheck FROM tablebase FOR UPDATE");
    #later $stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
    $result = $stmt->execute() or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR); #test error
    $stmt->bind_result($seat_status);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->store_result();
    echo 2;
    if ($seat_status === "0") {
        $stmt_bgn = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, deposit_current FROM userbase WHERE username=? AND pass =? AND deposit_current>0 AND seat=0 FOR UPDATE" );
        $stmt_bgn->bind_param('ss', $playername, $pass);
        $stmt_bgn->execute();
        $result = $stmt_bgn->execute() or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR); #test error
        $stmt_bgn->bind_result($usern,$deposit_current);
        $stmt_bgn->store_result();
        $stmt_bgn->fetch();
        $num_rows=$stmt_bgn->num_rows;
        echo 3;
        if ($num_rows == 1) {
            $stmt3 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tablebase SET $seatcheck=?, $chipscheck = ?");
            if(!$stmt3) {die('prepare4 failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));}
            $stmt3->bind_param('si', $playername, $deposit_current);
            $stmt3->execute();
            $stmt3->store_result();
            $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE userbase SET deposit_current=deposit_current-deposit_current, seat=? WHERE username=? AND pass=?");
            if(!$stmt2) {die('prepare4 failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));}
            #update above later for when deposit_current allows user to select their buy-in amount
            $stmt2->bind_param('iss', $seat, $playername, $pass);
            $stmt2->execute();
            if(!$stmt2) {die('prepare4 failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));}
            $result = $stmt2->execute() or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);
            $stmt2->store_result();
            if(!$stmt2) {die('prepare4 failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));}
            mysqli_autocommit($conn, TRUE);
            echo  4;
        }
    }
}
```

All the error catching is just temporary not for production, I'm trying to isolate this issue. No errors are thrown or displayed anywhere. I have full error reporting enabled.

It seems to me that there may be a lag, dropout to the MySQL server.. but if this is the case then why is "234" showing in the console, indicating that the SELECT statements are going through?

When I check the error log, nothing is there. slow_log shows nothing, and general_log shows that the queries are in fact successfully executed (including the UPDATES, although no tables are effected, just the UPDATE query is successfully executed, strange?). This problem occurs both with and without the transaction, with and without SELECT FOR UPDATE.

Whatever the cause, I can't release this program if any malicious user can simply spam a function and clog the entire website. Any thoughts as to the cause and how to prevent it would be appreciated.

Comment: Because its inefficient. You're locking the whole table with `select...FOR UPDATE` and then running through all the records only to find the ones where `seatstatus` is 0.  Seems obvious you need a where clause in that first query with `where seatstatus=0`

Comment: There's a lot of `FOR UPDATE` locks in here, which is going to be trouble. Why can't you do this inside a transaction block?

Comment: Just to clarify I only added the FOR UPDATES much later as part of a debugging attempt. I've removed them now but still no difference. The first SELECT (before echo 2) represents the seat the player wants to sit down on. The function will only allow the player to sit on their desired seats provided they have a seat status of "0" meaning they aren't currently seated anywhere.

Comment: 0 doesn't mean there was an error, it means nothing was ran or nothing was found to be ran on. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php « Zero indicates that no records where updated for an UPDATE/DELETE statement, no rows matched the WHERE clause in the query or that no query has yet been executed. -1 indicates that the query has returned an error. »

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this as mentioned in the question. The question is why if I spam the button it effects 0 rows instead of 1 row, but if I don't spam it it effects 1 row as predicted